# How to do transfer learning SSD object detection in Keras using saved model description and weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

If I have the saved description and weights of the model in json and .h5 files respectively, how can i continue/transfer training the SSD model in Keras on additional data? Which Keras SSD implementation would be simple to do this? https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/ssd_keras?

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
with open("path_to_json_file.json") as json_file:
    model = model_from_json(json_file.read())
    model.load_weights("path_to_weights_file.h5")
```

Comment: Take a look at Tensorflow.keras load model guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#introduction). Thanks!